# Is it possible to design an algorithm to estimate the future state?

Tags: computability

I wonder if we take the current state of our machine as input, is it possible to generate a function to estimate the future state?

Of course I mean like we get the 10 minutes after status within 1 minute of computing.

Is it a possible things? If not, then why is it impossible?

I know it's quite a weird question. : )

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I think you're going to need to [edit] the question to provide more context.  What kind of machine are you talking about?  What do you mean by "estimate"?  If my estimate is always 42, is that good enough?  It's an estimate (just not a very good one).  How do you plan to evaluate answers?  What are your thoughts?  What's the motivation or context for why you are asking?

Comment: Are you familiar with the time hierarchy theorem?